# Flutter extremely slow on linux

Tags: linux, flutter, flutter-desktop, flutter-linux

Flutter application is extremely slow on linux. The performance tab shows 15fps and it never goes beyond that. I was unable to find any explanation or possible solution for this issue. Any suggestions?

clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1/
cmake version 3.16.3/
ninja version 1.10.0/
pkg-config version 0.29.1/
OS : Fedora Linux

Comment: even on the most simple code created with `flutter create` command? what are the average frame times?

Comment: @pskink yeah it's not like it's got some crazy animations or anything. I run the same code on windows and I get solid 60fps. The avg fps never goes beyond 15 on linux tho. It's got nothing to do with the code itself. It's just generally extremely slow. Like when you hover over buttons and stuff like that

Comment: i have solid 60 FPS, Linux mint, flutter 3.6

Comment: @pskink the numbers are over 60 for me. sometimes even going as high as 230

Comment: and what does `top -i` command show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone potentially running into the same problem, this was either an issue with my OS or my flutter SDK. I initially installed the SDK using snap but after  reinstalling my OS I installed it by cloning the github repo and setting the path variable etc... (the way explained in the official website) and the issue was resolved.

Comment: sometimes I wish reinstalling OS would solve all my problems :D